# Nested ng-repeat for nav-tabs and tab-contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to loop through `ng-repeat (key, values)` and used `key` as tab header as well as  `href="#{{ key }}"`. Using the same `key` as id for tab-content-panel created new ng-repeat trying to access the parent `values`(values from parent ng-repeat). However not able to access the parent key, values in the tab-content elements. How can we use parent loop key, values in the child loop?

```html
<div>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" >
 <li class="active"  ng-repeat="(key, values) in specs" ng-class="{'active': isActive(key)}"><a  data-toggle="tab" href="#{{ key }}">{{ key }}</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
 <div id="{{ key }}" class="tab-pane fade in active">
  <table class="table" style="padding: 1 0px;">
     <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="(k, value) in values">
          <td>{{k}}</td>
          <td>{{value}}</td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>
 </div>
    
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use `ng-repeat="val in values"` and then you can use `{{val.k}}` and `{{val.value`

Comment: @JijoCleetus, Problem is not able to access values itself from parent loop, i'm fetching "values" from the parent ng-repeat since second loop is inside new element scope the parent values are not accessible.

Comment: please share your controller structure

Answer (score 0):

You need to set angular  ng-virtual-repeat value true.

refer this one. Here, set loop inside a loop

```
http://klajd.github.io/angular-virtual-repeat/#/Home

https://github.com/klajd/angular-virtual-repeat
```

Example :

```
<div>

<md-table-container virtual-repeat="true" sortable-columns="true" animate-sort-icon="true">
     <table md-table >
       <thead md-head>
          <tr md-row >
            <th md-column ng-repeat="header in headerData "><span> {{header}}</span></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

      <tbody md-body>
     <tr md-row ng-repeat="folder in Folders" style="height:30px"> 
         <th md-cell > <center><span style="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical"></span></center></th>
         <th md-cell ng-dblclick="openFolder(folder)" md-autofocus >{{folder.folderName}}</th>
       </tr>

        <tr md-row ng-repeat="files in fileData" style="height:30px" >
          <th md-cell ><center><span style="width: 10px; height: 15px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical"></span></center></th>
  <th md-cell  ng-click="getFileId(files)" md-autofocus >{{files.fileName}}</th></tr></tbody>
  </md-table-container>
  </div>
```